# Is it possible to make method generic without making class generic to return List<T>

Tags: java, generics, generic-list

Is it possible to make a method Generic without making class generic ?
Is there anyway to achieve below using generic type?

The code below does not compile, this is just to show what I want to achieve.

```
public class Test {

    public List<T> execute(String name, Map<String, Object> params,   List<T> type) {
          List<Object> emps = new ArrayList<Object>();
          emps.add(new Employee());
         //emps object will be generated dynamically 
         return (List<T>)emps;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.execute("testing", null, new ArrayList<Employee>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public <T> List<T> execute(String name, Map<String, Object> params, List<T> type) {
    List<Object> emps = new ArrayList<Object>();
    emps.add(new Employee());
    //emps object will be generated dynamically
    return (List<T>) emps;
}
```

Have a look at this explanation:

> The Java compiler takes advantage of target typing to infer the type
>   parameters of a generic method invocation. The target type of an
>   expression is the data type that the Java compiler expects depending
>   on where the expression appears. Consider the method
>   `Collections.emptyList`, which is declared as follows:
>
> `static <T> List<T> emptyList();` Consider the following assignment
>   statement:
>
> `List<String> listOne = Collections.emptyList();` This statement is
>   expecting an instance of `List<String>;` this data type is the target
>   type. Because the method `emptyList` returns a value of type `List<T>`,
>   the compiler infers that the type argument T must be the value String.
>   This works in both Java SE 7 and 8. Alternatively, you could use a
>   type witness and specify the value of T as follows:
>
> `List<String> listOne = Collections.<String>emptyList();`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can define a method as being generic in a non-generic class by declaring it as generic using the `<T>` notation.

Simple change the method signature to:

```
public <T> List<T> execute(String name, Map<String, Object> params, List<T> type)
```

And the method would be return a generic `List` object of type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below it should work

```
public List<?> execute(String name, Map<String, Object> params,   List<?> type) {

}
```